# Don't want recursive :after for my ul li dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck with this annoying problem. I have a nav in which there is a dropdown menu, composed by many `<ul>` in each `<li>`of the first `<ul>`

I have an :after effect for the main `<ul>`. It set a separator, but I don't want this separator in the `<ul><li>` of the `<ul><li>`.

Here is my code

```css
nav ul li {
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
  transition: background-color .3s;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  transition:0.5s all;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

nav ul li:after {
  height:60%;
  content:'';
  border-left: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255,0.3);

  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  left: 0px;
  top: 50%;

  transition:0.5s all;
      -webkit-transition: 0.5s all;
}

nav ul li ul li:after {
  content:none!important;
  height:0%!important;
  content:unset;
  border-left: unset;

  position: unset;
  transform: unset;
  left: unset;
  top: unset;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">

<nav>

<div class="bar">

<div class="brand-logo">
Paris Avenir</div>
<ul id="nav-normal" class="right">


        <li><a href="#">Aide/Tutos/Astuces<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>

        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">J'arrive à Paris</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Impositions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fonctionnement de la mairie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PLU</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Emploi/Formation</a></li>
        </ul>

        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Nos actions<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Décryptage des conseils municipaux</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Étude des budgets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Actualités</a></li>
        </ul></li>


        <li><a id="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a></li>


      </ul>

</div>

</nav>


</header>
```

This seems so easy but it doens't work.
Thanks you,
Matthieu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to select only the `ul` with the **id** of `nav-normal` and use the *child combinator* CSS selector:

```css
ul#nav-normal > li::after
```

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator

**Note that I've altered the styling of the `::after` elements to make then more easily visible**

```css
nav ul li {
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
  transition: background-color .3s;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  transition: 0.5s all;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

ul#nav-normal>li::after {
  content: '[:after content]';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">

  <nav>

    <div class="bar">

      <div class="brand-logo">Paris Avenir</div>

      <ul id="nav-normal" class="right">


        <li>
          <a href="#">Aide/Tutos/Astuces<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>

          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">J'arrive à Paris</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Impositions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fonctionnement de la mairie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PLU</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Emploi/Formation</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">Nos actions<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>

          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Décryptage des conseils municipaux</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Étude des budgets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Actualités</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a id="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a></li>


      </ul>

    </div>

  </nav>


</header>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't think about using the id !

Comment: My pleasure. Happy to help.